# Sonar error Conditions should not unconditionally evaluate to "TRUE" or to "FALSE"

Tags: java, collections, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am getting sonar violation:

> "Conditions should not unconditionally evaluate to "TRUE" or to "FALSE""

for the code below.

```
List<MediaContent> savedList = source.getChildMediaContents();
List<MediaContent> supplierList = target.getChildMediaContents();

// if existing and incoming both empty
if(savedList == null && supplierList == null){
    return false;
}

// if one is null and other is not then update is required
if(savedList == null && supplierList != null){
    return true;
}

if(savedList != null && supplierList == null){
    return true;
}
```

Below the two if blocks it is giving an error

```
// if one is null and other is not then update is required
if(savedList == null && supplierList != null){
    return true;
}

if(savedList != null && supplierList == null){
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> if(savedList == null && supplierList == null){
>     return false;
> }
>
> if(savedList == null && supplierList != null){
> ```

The condition `supplierList != null` is always true when reached.
Due to the short-circuiting behavior of the `&&` operator in Java,
before `supplierList != null` is reached,
`savedList == null` must be true first.

But if `savedList == null` is true,
then we know from the previous condition that `supplierList` is not `null`, so it's a pointless condition.

On the other hand, if `savedList == null` is false,
then the due to the short-circuiting behavior,
the `supplierList != null` will not be evaluated.

Thus, regardless of the outcome of `savedList == null`,
`supplierList != null` will never be evaluated,
so you can simply remove that condition.

```
if (savedList == null) {
    return true;
}
```

Next:

> ```
> if(savedList != null && supplierList == null){
> ```

Thanks to the simplification earlier, now it's clear that `savedList` cannot be `null`. So we can remove that condition too:

```
if (supplierList == null) {
    return true;
}
```

In short, this is equivalent to your posted code:

```
if (savedList == null && supplierList == null) {
    return false;
}

if (savedList == null || supplierList == null) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You could even merge the last two if clauses to `if (savedList == null || supplierList == null) return true`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the above you avoid the second two if conditions and have an else case

```
if(savedList == null && supplierList == null){
    return false;
} else {
    return true; // either savedList or supplierList is not null
}
```

or you can simply have return statement removing all the if statements

```
return (savedList != null || supplierList != null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
if(savedList == null && supplierList == null){
  return false;
}
return true;
```