# Sonar - Conditions should not unconditionally evaluate to "TRUE" or to "FALSE"

Tags: java

Hi I have written below code for to check to list equal or not

```
 private  boolean equalTypeLists(List<Type> one, List<Type> two){
    if (one == null && two == null){
        return true;
    }
    if((one == null && two != null)
            || one != null && two == null
            || one.size() != two.size()){
        return false;
    }
    one = new ArrayList<>(one);
    two = new ArrayList<>(two);

    Collections.sort(one, new Comparator<Type>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Type o1, Type o2) {
            return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
        }
    });
    Collections.sort(two, new Comparator<Type>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Type o1, Type o2) {
            return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
        }
    });

    return checkForTwoEqualTypeLists(one,two);
}
```

But Sonar is giving Blocker message "Conditions should not unconditionally evaluate to "TRUE" or to "FALSE"" for below line of code

```
if((one == null && two != null)
        || one != null && two == null
        || one.size() != two.size()){
    return false;
}
```

Please could you help me to resolve above scenario.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41228788/sonar-error-conditions-should-not-unconditionally-evaluate-to-true-or-to-fals

Comment: `if ((one == null && two != null) || (one != null && two == null) || (one.size() != two.size())) {
    return false;
}`

Comment: @DevendraLattu Yes, but can you explain _why_ Sonar is going bonkers over this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sonar error Conditions should not unconditionally evaluate to "TRUE" or to "FALSE"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41228788/sonar-error-conditions-should-not-unconditionally-evaluate-to-true-or-to-fals)

Answer (score 3):

From [sonar website](https://dev.eclipse.org/sonar/rules/show/squid:S2583):

**Conditions should not unconditionally evaluate to "TRUE" or to "FALSE"**

> Conditional statements using a condition which cannot be anything but
>   FALSE have the effect of making blocks of code non-functional. If the
>   condition cannot evaluate to anything but TRUE, the conditional
>   statement is completely redundant, and makes the code less readable.
>
> It is quite likely that the code does not match the programmer's
>   intent. Either the condition should be removed or it should be updated
>   so that it does not always evaluate to TRUE or FALSE.

The last sentence help to identify the correction to bring:

**Either the condition should be removed or it should be updated so that it does not always evaluate to TRUE or FALSE.**

In your case, conditional statements spot by Sonar as rule violations should not be updated but removed because even if these are correct, these are also redundant.

---

In this code, if the `if` statement is `false`, it means that at least `one` or `two` (and maybe even both) is not `null` :

```
if (one == null && two == null){
    return true;
}
```

But in the second `if` statement, you repeat this test:

```
if((one == null && two != null)
        || one != null && two == null
        || one.size() != two.size()){
    return false;
}
```

The checks `!= null` here : `(one == null && two != null)` and `one != null && two == null` are not required as we know that when we reach this code, if one of them (`one` or `two`) is `null`, the other one is necessarily not `null` (conclusion of the first `if` statement).

So this should be enough :

```
if (one == null && two == null){
    return true;
}

if(one == null || two == null || one.size() != two.size()){
    return false;
}
```